# Using $scope with $parse

Tags: angularjs

I want to find the value of a parsed text in angular.
For example:
I know i can set the scope value of a variable text like following

```
var text = 'randomString';
$parse(text).assign($scope, 1234);
```

But i do not need to set the value.  Instead i want to retrieve it. I tried `console.log($parse('randomString'))`, but it prints out a function. I tried `console.log($scope.$parse('randomString'))`, but it throws an error saying it is not a function.

I know i can use `$scope.randomString` in the above example but i need the string to be dynamic so i do not know what the string will actually be

How can i retrieve the value?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I came across a solution online. I used:

```
console.log($scope.$eval('randomString'));
```